# Анимация в tkinter (Рамки). необходимо сделать рамки в игре, чтобы рыцарь не улетал за наше окно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()
w=600
h=600
window.geometry(str(w)+"x"+str(h))
 
canvas = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)         
canvas.place(in_=window, x=0, y=0)         
 
bg_image = PhotoImage(file="bg_2.png")         
 
class Knight:        
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=70
        self.y=h/2
        self.v=0
 
        self.photo=PhotoImage(file="knight.png")
          
    def up (self ,event):
        self.v=-3   
    def down(self, event):
        self.v=3
    def stop(self, event):
        self.v=0
class Dragon:       
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=750
        self.y=random.randint(100,500)
        self.v=random.randint(1,4)
 
        self.photo=PhotoImage(file="dragon.png")
 
 
knight = Knight()
 
dragons=[]
for i in range(3):
    dragons.append(Dragon())
 
 
 
 
def game():
    canvas.delete("all")        
    canvas.create_image(300,300, image=bg_image)      
    canvas.create_image(knight.x, knight.y, image=knight.photo)
 
    knight.y += knight.v
 
    current_dragon=0         
    dragon_to_kill=-1         
 
    for dragon in dragons:
        dragon.x-=dragon.v
        canvas.create_image(dragon.x, dragon.y, image=dragon.photo)
 
        if((dragon.x-knight.x)**2) + ((dragon.y-knight.y)**2)<=(96)**2:
            dragon_to_kill=current_dragon
 
        current_dragon+=1
 
        if dragon.x <=0:
            canvas.delete("all")
            canvas.create_text(w // 2, h // 2, text="You Lose...", font="Verdana 42", fill="black")
            break
 
 
    if dragon_to_kill != -1:
        del dragons [dragon_to_kill]        
 
    if len(dragons)==0:
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas.create_text(w//2, h//2, text ="You Win!!!", font="Verdana 42", fill="black")
 
 
    else:
        window.after(5, game)
 
 
 
 
game()
 
 
window.bind("<Key-Up>", knight.up)
window.bind("<Key-Down>", knight.down)
window.bind("<KeyRelease>", knight.stop)
 
 
 
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
w = 600
h = 600
window.geometry(f'{w}x{h}')

canvas = Canvas(window, width=w, height=h)
canvas.place(in_=window, x=0, y=0)
bg_photo = PhotoImage(file='bg_2.png')



class Knight:

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 70
        self.y = h // 2
        self.v = 0
        self.v_x = 0
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file='cat.png')

    def up(self, event):
        self.v = -3

    def down(self, event):
        self.v = +3

    def right(self, event):
        self.v_x = +3

    def left(self, event):
        self.v_x = -3

    def stop_all(self, event):
        self.v = 0
        self.v_x = 0


class Dragon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(700, 1500)
        self.y = random.randint(100, 500)
        self.v = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.photo = PhotoImage(file='dragon.png')


knight = Knight()
dragons = []
for i in range(10):
    dragons.append(Dragon())


def game():
    canvas.delete('all')
    canvas.create_image(h // 2, w // 2, image=bg_photo)
    canvas.create_image(knight.x, knight.y, image=knight.photo)
    knight.y += knight.v
    knight.x += knight.v_x
    canvas.create_image(knight.x, knight.y, image=knight.photo)
    kill_dragon = -1
    for i, dragon in enumerate(dragons):
        dragon.x -= dragon.v
        canvas.create_image(dragon.x, dragon.y, image=dragon.photo)

        if ((dragon.x - knight.x) ** 2 + (dragon.y - knight.y) ** 2) <= 95 ** 2:
            kill_dragon = i
        if dragon.x <= 0:
            canvas.delete('all')
            canvas.create_text(w // 2.3, h // 2.3, text='you lose ', font='System 42', fill='red')
            break

    if kill_dragon > -1:
        del dragons[kill_dragon]

    if len(dragons) == 0:
        canvas.delete('all')
        canvas.create_text(w // 2, h // 2, text='gg you win', font='System 42', fill='red')

    if knight.y <= 52:
        knight.y = 53
    if knight.y >= 544:
        knight.y = 543
    if knight.x <= 50:
        knight.x = 51
    if knight.x >= 550:
        knight.x = 551
    window.after(5, game)

window.bind('<Key-Up>', knight.up)
window.bind('<Key-Down>', knight.down)
window.bind('<Key-Right>', knight.right)
window.bind('<Key-Left>', knight.left)
window.bind('<KeyRelease>', knight.stop_all)

window.resizable(height=False, width=False)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]